# How can I ping update-core.php with a script?

Tags: theme-development, updates

I have the paid Divi theme on many websites on a cPanel powered server.  I use WP-CLI in a bash script to update all the plugins and themes.  But Divi will never update because it only reveals an update is available when you visit wp-admin/update-core.php  When you visit that main update page with a browser, you'll see the update number next to "Updates" magically grow by +1.

What I want to do is call update-core.php so it runs one time, because after that happens, WP-CLI is able to detect the Divi update without any problem.  At least this is what I think I want to do.  Clearly I'm open to suggestions.

What I've tried so far:

This is the php script in the public web root:

```
<?php
define( 'WP_ADMIN', true );
ignore_user_abort(true);
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
//define( 'SHORTINIT', true );
require( $path.'/wp-load.php' );
require( $path.'/wp-admin/update-core.php' );
```

But calling that from a browser just goes to a login screen, because it fails the current_user_can checks at the beginning of update-core.php  Should I try to create a hacked version of update-core.php that has no user checks? Am I pursuing the wrong path entirely?

There was a discussion on GitHub but I was not able to get the --require feature to work with a script containing `define( 'WP_ADMIN', true );`

https://github.com/wp-cli/extension-command/issues/106

The bash script I use to bulk update is like this--

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a arr=(
"account1"
"account2"
"account3"
                )

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "$i"
   echo ______________________________________________________
   cd /home/"$i"/www
   wp core update-db --allow-root
   wp core update --allow-root
   wp plugin update --all --allow-root
   wp theme update --all --allow-root
   chown -R "$i":"$i" *
done
```

Comment: I'd guess Divi has its own way of doing an update detection, separate from wp_update_themes, that gets triggered by update-core somehow. I'd read the theme code to work out what that is and trigger it directly rather than trying to load the update-core page. I'd guess it adds itself to the `'update_themes'` site transient when there is an update so you could start by searching for that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP-CLI was updated to include a new global parameter that allows the execution of arbitrary PHP code before the main command runs. This allows you to pass the is_admin() check that some themes and plugins use.

```
wp plugin update --all --exec="define( 'WP_ADMIN', true );"
```